# How to solve Invariant violation: maximum update depth exceeded in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my React-native project I want to change one image depending on a TouchableOpacity element onPress. So, I have declared one variable inside state - catImage . For changing the Image I have declared one function named updateImage

```
  updateImage(image) {
    this.setState({
        catImage: image
    })
  }
```

In the below you can see the demo of this class-

[image]

In (ToDo)icons in horizontal scroll, by pressing them I want to change the value of catImage variable and the Image beside Title TextInput marked in the first image.

Here's the code of the class- HelloWorldApp.js

**HelloWorldApp.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Image, TextInput, NetInfo, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {

    state = {

        isLoading:false,
      }

      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          title:'',
          details:'',
          timestamp   : '',
          status: '',
          url:'',
          mail:'',
          phone:'',
          category:'',
          showLoader:false,
          showAlert: false,
          isNetConnected: true,
          catImage: null,
        }
      };

      updateImage(image) {
        this.setState({
            catImage: image
        })
      }

      updateValue(text, field) {

        if(field == 'title') {
          this.setState({
            title : text
          })
        }


        else if(field == 'details') {
          this.setState({
            details : text
          })
        }

      }

      // net connection starts
componentDidMount() {

    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
      "connectionChange",
      this.handleConnectivityChange
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
      "connectionChange",
      this.handleConnectivityChange
    );
  }
  handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
    if (isConnected) {
      this.setState({ isConnected });
    } else {
      this.state.isNetConnected = false;
      alert("Oops!! No Internet Connection Available");
      this.setState({ isConnected });
    }
  };
  // net connection ends


  render() {
    return (

        <View style={{flex:1}}>

            <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>

            <View style={styles.container}>

                <View style={styles.inputContainerEmail}>
                <Image style={styles.inputIcon} source={{uri: this.state.catImage}}/>
                <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                    placeholder="Title"
                    keyboardType="email-address"
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.updateValue(text, 'email')}/>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.inputContainerDetails}>

                <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                    placeholder="Details"
                    multiline 

                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.updateValue(text, 'email')}/>
                </View>


                <ScrollView horizontal={true}>

                <View style={{flexDirection:'row', flex:1, marginTop:10, marginBottom:10, marginRight:20, marginLeft:10}}>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', marginRight:10}}
                       onPress={this.updateImage('https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/todo-list.png')}
                    >
                    <Image style={styles.inputIconCategory} source={{uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/todo-list.png'}}/>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:25, marginTop:5}}>To Do</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', marginRight:10}}>
                    <Image style={styles.inputIconCategory} source={{uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/todo-list.png'}}/>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:25, marginTop:5}}>To Do</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', marginRight:10}}>
                    <Image style={styles.inputIconCategory} source={{uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/todo-list.png'}}/>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:25, marginTop:5}}>To Do</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', marginRight:10}}>
                    <Image style={styles.inputIconCategory} source={{uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/todo-list.png'}}/>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:25, marginTop:5}}>To Do</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', marginRight:10}}>
                    <Image style={styles.inputIconCategory} source={{uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/todo-list.png'}}/>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:25, marginTop:5}}>To Do</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', marginRight:10}}>
                    <Image style={styles.inputIconCategory} source={{uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/todo-list.png'}}/>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:25, marginTop:5}}>To Do</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', marginRight:10}}>
                    <Image style={styles.inputIconCategory} source={{uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/todo-list.png'}}/>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:25, marginTop:5}}>To Do</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', marginRight:10}}>
                    <Image style={styles.inputIconCategory} source={{uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/todo-list.png'}}/>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:25, marginTop:5}}>To Do</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>

                </ScrollView>

            </View>

            </ScrollView>

        </View>


    );
  }
}
```

But whenever I run the project It shows the following error-
How to solve Invariant violation: maximum update depth exceeded in React-Native?

So, I want to know how I can change the Image beside the Title TextInput by click the icons at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Why are you defining state twice? Either define it all inside the constructor, or all outside the constructor, don't mix and match the declarations. Also try making your `updateImage(image) {` into and arrow function `updateImage = (image) =>  {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', marginRight:10}}
                       onPress={()=>{this.updateImage('https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/todo-list.png')}}
                    >
                    <Image style={styles.inputIconCategory} source={{uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/todo-list.png'}}/>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:25, marginTop:5}}>To Do</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Just use the Arrow function in your first component **TouchableOpacity**.

```
 onPress={()=>{this.updateImage('https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/todo-list.png')}}
```

Comment: This one is usefull. Thanks